# Wordpress + bbPress registration user-unfriendly?

Tags: user-registration

I'm testing Wordpress + bbPress (both latest versions):

http://alexchen.info/

When I press Register it sends me to Wordpress' backend login page (I'm no longer in the site).

If I click the [Registration User](http://alexchen.info/registration-form/) page, and fill my username and email it sends me to Worpdpress' backend login page again and it says: `ERROR: The password field is empty.`

Is there a way of letting the user just sign up while being on the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this Article http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/ provides a great tutorial on how to create you own frontend register/login/restore password forms.

or if you are looking for a plugin then i've used these before and can recommend them:

- [Ajax Login/Register](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-loginregister/)
- [Login With Ajax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/login-with-ajax/)
- [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/)

Comment: Thanks for the info but sorry, which article?

Comment: @janoChen i added the link, sorry

Comment: Glad i could help